# Not able to build OpenBMC

Tags: python, ubuntu, bitbake, openbmc

I downloaded open bmc code in Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. I am trying to build the open bmc and getting the below errors. Any suggestions

```
Starting build
++ bitbake obmc-phosphor-image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
        ++ bitbake obmc-phosphor-image
                Traceback (most recent call last):
                 ...
                AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signature'
                ERROR: Error evaluating '${@oe_import(d)}'
                Traceback (most recent call last):
                File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bb/data_smart.py", line 117, in expandWithRefs
                        s = __expand_python_regexp__.sub(varparse.python_sub, s)
                File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bb/data_smart.py", line 76, in python_sub
                value = utils.better_eval(codeobj, DataContext(self.d))
                File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bb/utils.py", line 387, in better_eval
                        return eval(source, _context, locals)
                File "<expansion>", line 1, in <module>
                File "base.bbclass", line 14, in oe_import
                AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signature'
```

Comment: Error Details "                                 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signature'
ERROR: Error evaluating '${@oe_import(d)}'
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: I could fix it by removing the Python3 from the system .

Answer (score 0):

There were two pyhton version installed. Python3 was not matching with the openBMC code base I used. I uninstall the python3. Then the error disappeared.